# UITextView in UITableViewCell scroll to location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView in a UITableViewCell. They both dynamically size itself to fit. The problem I have is that when the texview reaches below the bottom of the screen (from making new lines), the tableView does not scroll to its location.

I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add code below to scroll the tableView too:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange];
    // since you are only scrolling the table a little bit and not by a whole cell, then change the scrollView.offset
    CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;
    offset.x += 20;  // an example.  You need to change this based on the new size of the textview.
    tableView.contentOffset = offset;
}
```

Comment: As I said, that is an example.  You need to modify that according to what it is you are trying to do.  The tableView itself won't scroll up automatically.
I modified the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the cell containing the `textView` and tell the table view to scroll to that cell:

```
UIView *parentView = textView.superview;
while(![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    parentView = parentView.superview;
}
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)parentView];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think what this does, is tries to center the textview on the screen, because it didn't work as expected. If I make enough new lines, it won't show

Comment: I just figured out that by UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle. You have to change 'Middle', to bottom